# Closure called immediately using Alamo fire

Tags: ios, swift, callback, closures, block

I am writing a small wrapper around some Alamo fire calls and getting some issues with closures, the closure is called prior to Alamo fires response

```swift
var manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default {
   didSet {
      self.manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
   }
}

//Create my function signature
func sendInformation(parameters: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: String?) -> Void) {
   //helper for creating params / headers etc 
   let request = HelperRequest().submitNewPassport(parameters: parameters)

   manager.request(request.requestURL,
      method: request.method,
      parameters: request.parameters,
      encoding: request.encoding,
      headers: request.headers).responseJSON { (response) in
         print("** Updated called")
         if response.result.isSuccess {
            //show success
            completion(true, nil)
            return
         } else {
            //show error
            completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
            return
         }
completion(false, nil)
```

However, when this is called I get a failure completion immediately before a the request is made and a following correct callback

```swift
sendInformation(parameters: params,  { (success, error) -> Void in
   if success {
      print("** success")
   } else {
      print("** error ")
   }
```

The log looks as follows

```
** error 
** Updated called
** Success
```

Comment: I think you have some freaky `error` log in `HelperRequest` initializer or `submitNewPassport` method because `sendInformation` looks completely fine.

Comment: @Kamran Crazy right? `HelperRequest.submitNewPassport ` is just an enum that contains the parameters and headers etc, I don't think  thats causing any problems its only providing Alamo fire with data  - the request works correctly, however the closure is called before the request is made, then after (as expected the second time) really puzzled

Comment: Just print the coming `error` and see if you can get some useful information. Or put a breakpoint inside the `sendInformation` completion.

Comment: Thats exactly it though @Kamran the closure is called immediately before the `sendInformation` completion is called or the `response` in the Alamo fire completion - the result is `false, nil` its like its created initially

Comment: Ah Found the issue -  there was a rogue completion out side of the block! what a n00b!